# SL cross domain calls on localhost

Tags: silverlight

I have read up on the Cross-Domain policy from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx). How do we get it to work while testing on localhost, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Silverlight client application should try to call service hosted in different machine from web-site that hosts Silverlight app.

Comment: Ok, so we make changes and just update the website - that is how we test it?

Comment: If you want test clientaccesspolicy, can browse silverlight app. using other machines.